# Array get next/previous elements

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array of id's: $products=array(2151, 2563, 2015, 1986, 1985);

What i want is to build a function that will return the next and the previous item each time i pass an id. For example when i have lets say the 2563-id to get a response with 2151 & 2015.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: where do you get your ids? how many of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$index = array_search($id, $products);
if($index !== FALSE)
{
  $next = $products[$index + 1];
  $previous = $products[$index - 1];
}
```

Then you do the checks since `$products[$index +/- 1]` will not always exist!

Comment: usually you do the checks first, then calculate `$index +/- 1` or what is `false +/- 1`?

Comment: @duedl0r: Thanks. Edited the answer now. I didn't account for the return value of `array_search()`. The checks I was referring to was for `$next` and `$previous`

Comment: I think, you sould still check if `$products` is set at `$index +/- 1`.

Comment: i think i got the point. i ll do the check and everything will be ok. Thanks!

Comment: @Yoshi: Yes. That's what I was referring to in the last sentence. =) Thanks for emphasizing it.

Comment: 9 Years later, this works a charm. @RolandoCruz Thank you. 1 hours google search only 1 positive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I case you would have spec keys, then `next()` and `prev()` functions is better.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php